# C compiling - 'undefined reference to function' when trying to link object files

Tags: c

so i create the object files with

```
cc -c MAIN.C
cc -c tablero.c
```

but then when i try to link them to an executable with

```
cc MAIN.o tablero.o
```

i get

```
undefined reference to `asdf()'
```

(function defined in tablero.c and called in MAIN.C)

**here are my files:**

i have MAIN.C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include "tablero.h"
int main()
{
   int c;
   printf( "Enter a value :");
   c = getchar( );
   putchar(c);
   printf( "\nYou entered: ");
   c = asdf ();
   putchar(c);
   return 0;
}
```

i have tablero.h

```
#ifndef TABLERO_H_
#define TABLERO_H_
int asdf();
#endif // TABLERO_H_
```

and i have tablero.c

```
#include "tablero.h"
int asdf() {return 48;}; //48 is 0 in ascii
```

Comment: works on my system(ubuntu gnome 16.04, although i had to remove cstring)

Comment: Note that `<cstring>` is a C++ header and not a C header.  It's not clear that you need that, though — regardless of language.

Comment: @PriyeshKumar: Did you really name the file "MAIN.C" and not, for example, "MAIN.c"?

Comment: yeah, i missed that. I used small c

Comment: +1 for actually showing both a complete, minimal example and _the actual file names and commands_, with case and everything!

Comment: I feel like this should get a revised title to make it easier for people in the future to discover when this is their problem, but I can't actually think of one :-/

Comment: BTW: _Declaring_ a function like `int asdf();` does not warn if someone called it with `asdf(1,2,3);` as there is no prototype for the arguments.  Better to use `int asdf(void);`.  The `void` is not needed in the _definition_ `int asdf() {...}`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have been bitten by an obscure feature of the `cc` tool on many Unixy systems: files whose suffix is lowercase `.c` are compiled as C, but files whose suffix is *uppercase* `.C` are compiled as C++!  Therefore, your `main` (compiled as C++) contains an external reference to a *mangled* function name, `asdf()` (aka `_Z4asdfv`), but `tablero.o` (compiled as C) defines only an *unmangled* name, `asdf`.

This is also why you were able to include the C++ header file `<cstring>` in what was meant to be a C program.

Rename `MAIN.C` to `main.c` (and change `<cstring>` to `<string.h>`), recompile `main.o`, and your program should link.

If you actually *want* to compile part of your program as C and part as C++, then you can annotate your header files with `extern "C"` to make the symbols match up:

```
#ifndef TABLERO_H_
#define TABLERO_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int asdf(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // TABLERO_H_
```

Header files like this have to be extra careful to contain only code that has the same meaning in C and C++.  Only POD types, no C++ keywords, no C99-but-not-C++ keywords either, no overloads, et cetera.